# Using a bot to open embed hyperlinks sent in a discord channel by another bot

Tags: json, hyperlink, discord, bots, embed

**Situation**: 3rd Party Discord Bot sends masked URL in case of certain events into a private discord channel as an embedded message, instead of clicking on them manually the goal is to have another bot opening those hyperlinks automatically.

**Current Status**: With a lot of research (also on stack overflow) I managed to get to the following state that will open hyperlinks that are sent as normal text in the respective discord channel or that are included in the description of an embedded message (Kudos to Zach C & Daemon Beast):

```
client.on("message", message => {
        if (message.channel.id == config.channelIds) {
            
            //first part analyses normal messages
            if (message.content.includes("https")) {
                var link = message.content.split("https")[1]
                console.log(link)
                var linktest = `https${link}`
                console.log(`opening ${linktest}`)
                open(linktest)
            }
             
            //second part analyses embeded messsages                  
            else if (message.embeds) {
                message.embeds.forEach(embed => {
                if (embed.description.includes("https")){
                    var link = embed.description.split("https")[1];
                    link = link.replace(")", "");
                    console.log(link);
                    var linktest = `https${link}`;
                    console.log(`opening ${linktest}`);
                    open(linktest);
                }
            });
            }
        }
})
```

**Testing**: Testing was done using another Bot sending embedded hyperlinks. When they were embedded in the Body/Description the hyperlinks are being opened just fine.

```
//Testing Bot:
    {"content": null,
      "embeds": [
        {
          "title": "Test Title",
          "description": "Test Description",
          "color": 2108322,
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "Test Name",
              "value": "Test Value\n[Click here to test](https://google.com)"
            }]}]}
```

**Problem**: In this particular use case hyperlinks are not included in the body/description but rather in the field value which currently not being recognized by the bot and thus not opened.

I already went tough a couple of hours of research & trial/error but was not able to change the code in a way that it would work.
I have tried to use "some" functionality

```
if (embed.fields.some(f => f.value.includes("https")))
```

and "includes"

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes("https"))
```

But while with the some functionality I was able to make some progress by getting a return value "true" I struggle in adjusting the "var link =" in a way to then get to a proper link.

I have used the replace function to remove the closing bracket ) from the hyperlink.

I feel like I have reached 95% and there is only a small adjustment necessary that the code actually targets the right fields in the embedded message.
Your support is very much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion I would like to share the found solution, there would be better ones with loops but this one worked for me as the link is always at the same place in the embed:

```
else if (message.embeds) {
                message.embeds.forEach(embed => {
                console.log(message.embeds[0].fields[8].value);
                if (embed.fields[6].value.includes("https")){
                    var link = embed.fields[6].value.split("https")[1];
                    link = link.replace(")", "");
                    console.log(link);
                    var linktest = `https${link}`;
                    console.log(`opening ${linktest}`);
                    open(linktest);
```